# an archive site That Works? (without credit card)

Tags: screenshot, archiving

(A common problem it is that folks want to "save" what they see on a laptop when browsing. And the only two  solutions that work is Archive.is and archive.org.)

However, **they don't work all the time.**

Per <[web.archive.org/web/20240216001105/https://webapps.stackexchange.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20240216001105/https://webapps.stackexchange.com)> and <[archive.is/wip/YcYDH](https://archive.is/wip/YcYDH)>, I am not able to see the Google Cloud Ad which can be seen on the page <[webapps.stackexchange.com/](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/)> right now.

The current solution I use is to take a screenshot and put it up on maybe imgur/imgbb. There are several problems with this approach but the top 2 pain are:

1. Browser is unable to manage a screenshot. (So guess what, I have to manage it and that extra seconds/minutes per screenshot adds up fast.)
2. [For anything greater than 2mb] I have to use an imgur/imgbb and these sites are a pain. For example they are laggy, and two, are not byDesigned for archiving. so x% of times I **must** archive that imgur/imgbb on an archive site. Man, that even feels redundant.

**Need a solution** that is better than my current solution. Any ideas?

---

- I wish not to install  another Yet Another extension for / that does just this one thing. but I don't believe one That Works even exists.
- Answers like <Get a Windows doh> etc will get my bitcoin address.
- Chromebooks cannot do a screenshot to ram. (so you have to delete the trailing files but the problem is that at many (or all) times you **mustn't/cannot** write to file even if there is no connection to a monitoring printer in another room.)
- Chromebooks devtools cannot do a screenshot to ram.

Comment: First thing first, what is your goal? Archiving for what purpose? Read again? Interact with the page later? Legal purposes? Etc

Comment: @NicolasRaoul, in order to show/see again for maybe legal purposes or otherwise.